# Datastax OpsCenter not showing nodes

Tags: datastax

I installed datastax enterprise  in my win7 system,but it is not displaying any node in opscenter dashboard.(Actually I have re-installed the datastax due to some issue in previous installation.)

I am getting the node detail in command line using nodetool command,but no node is present in the datastax ops center dashboard.

I think OpsCenter agent is failing to connect the node.

Please help me

Thanks,
Subhra

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to be more concrete, deliver a programming example and so on.

Comment: If you're seeing the "1 node" in the OpsCenter dashboard, just not seeing full information for that node, check that the agent service is running and that there are no errors in the logs.  Otherwise, please provide more details about your setup, what you're seeing, and any relevant information from the log files.

Answer (score 1):

The agent might not be started on your system in linux its in /usr/share/datastax-agent/bin run the 'install_agent'.

Also check if the ports for running opscenter are not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below mentioned procedure :

1) Check datastax-agent is installed on nodes and also service is running.

2) Check Port connection is open for datastax-agent.
   http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/opscenter/5.1/opsc/reference/opscPorts_r.html

3) Reconfigure your existing Cluster details in Opscenter, after deleting previous configuration in Opscenter.

4) If issue still exist check log file of opscenter (opscenterd.log)